# How do I go about testing this code in jest?

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, jestjs

I'm pretty new to mocking and I understand assertions and find them easy. However, mocking is racking my brain. I have a vue project in typescript. Thing is, I'm stuck and don't know how to go about testing the API calls that I've exposed as service classes.

### My Thinking and Code Design

#### apiClient

I have created a single axios instance called "apiClient" so I can have the custom config available at any time. I have stored this at the root of my project.

#### Services

I have created each endpoint of the API as a "service" in my services folder
Each service is a class with a bunch of functions in it that I will use to get the data that I need.

### My Questions

- My understanding is that you want to mock all dependencies, So do I need to start with my custom axios instance?
- Do I need to mock the class as well?
- How would I go about mocking this in general? I know in development the most general answer is, "it depends" but I've been walking through the jest docs and I don't find some of it clear. (Maybe it's me approaching it for an answer)
- What all do I need to mock?

### My Code

#### ExampleService.ts

```
import Approval from '@/interfaces/Approval';
import apiClient from '@/axiosConfig';
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

export default class ExampleService {
    // Approvals
    public async getApprovals(id?: string) {
        if (id != null || id !== undefined) {
            return await apiClient
            .get(`/api//approval/${id}`)
            .then((response: AxiosResponse<Approval>) => {
                return response.data;
            });

        } else {
            return await apiClient
            .get('/api/approval')
            .then((response: AxiosResponse<Approval[]>) => {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }

    public async postApproval(approval: Approval) {
        return await apiClient
        .post('/api/approval', approval);
    }

    public async putAppoval(id: string, approval: Approval) {
        return await apiClient
        .put(`/api/approval/${id}`, approval);
    }

    public async deleteApproval(id: string) {
        return await apiClient
        .delete(`/api/approval/${id}`);
    }
}
```

#### CustomAxiosInstance.ts

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_API}`,
});

export default apiClient;
```

### My Expectations

Would love some example code of how I would mock this and some explanation over why you chose to do the method you chose. Please critique my code as well. I only want to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit test for this class is nothing related to `Vue.js`, here is the solution, folder structure:

```sh
├── ExampleService.ts
├── __tests__
│   └── ExampleService.spec.ts
├── axiosConfig.ts
└── interfaces
    └── Approval.ts

2 directories, 4 files
```

Unit test, `ExampleService.spec.ts`:

```js
import ExampleService from '../ExampleService';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios', () => {
  return {
    create: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    get: jest.fn()
  };
});

const exampleService = new ExampleService();

describe('ExampleService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    (axios.create().get as jest.MockedFunction<typeof axios.get>).mockReset();
  });

  describe('#getApprovals', () => {
    const mockedResponse: AxiosResponse = {
      data: 'mocked data',
      status: 200,
      statusText: 'ok',
      headers: {},
      config: {}
    };
    it('should get approvals by id correctly', async () => {
      (axios.create().get as jest.MockedFunction<typeof axios.get>).mockResolvedValueOnce(mockedResponse);
      const actualValue = await exampleService.getApprovals('1');
      expect(actualValue).toEqual(mockedResponse.data);
      expect(axios.create().get).toBeCalledWith(`/api/approval/1`);
    });

    it('should get approvals correctly', async () => {
      (axios.create().get as jest.MockedFunction<typeof axios.get>).mockResolvedValueOnce(mockedResponse);
      const actualValue = await exampleService.getApprovals();
      expect(actualValue).toEqual(mockedResponse.data);
      expect(axios.create().get).toBeCalledWith(`/api/approval`);
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57992553/__tests__/ExampleService.spec.ts (7.041s)
  ExampleService
    #getApprovals
      ✓ should get approvals by id correctly (14ms)
      ✓ should get approvals correctly (3ms)

-------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File               |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files          |    73.91 |    53.85 |    57.14 |    83.33 |                   |
 ExampleService.ts |       70 |    53.85 |    57.14 |       80 |          19,23,27 |
 axiosConfig.ts    |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.532s
```

I only test `getApprovals` method, you can test the other methods in the same way.

Above unit test based on:

```
"jest": "^24.8.0",
"@types/jest": "^24.0.17",
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57992553

Comment: Thank you for the help. I only have one more question, my linter is only yelling at one part, jest.MockedFunction in lines 15, 27,and 34.

any
Namespace 'jest' has no exported member 'MockedFunction'.ts(2694)

Comment: @Sanwil9 It could be the version issue. Please check and upgrade

Comment: Ah, yea, my package.json was generated by the vue cli "ts-jest": "^23.0.0" ,"@types/jest": "^23.1.4",     "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.11.0",

Comment: I will commit current state, upgrade, if it breaks, I'll revert back. I have no clue where all I have to reconfigure anything if it's necessary. I'll have to hunt in the docs

Comment: Also, I updated everything to match. It's still complaining. ts-jest is saying it's not suppported and everything jest related is highlighted

Comment: @Sanwil9 Can you take a look at the demo, check the version and configuration